# Calculating list of subnets that make a given IP range

Tags: c++, networking, ip, cidr

I am trying to come up with and understand a function `IPv4Range (startIPAddr, endIPAddr)` which will return a list of CIDR ranges.

For example:

```
  10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.3  ->  10.0.0.0/30
  10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.6  ->  10.0.0.0/30, 10.0.0.4/31, 10.0.0.6/32
```

and even more complicated cases.

I've previously found many online examples of this code to look at, but some of them don't work at all and the rest of them are returning smallest common subnet (like 10.0.0.0/29 contains 10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.4 but they are not equal so it's not what I expect) rather than the entire range.

Answer (score 4):

First of all this is not a site to get a working code without trying to write something yourself. However I will explain how I would approach this problem and give you a code that can be easily adopted to your needs.

This problem is easy if you have ranges that define a single scope like `10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.255` so lets get something more complex, for example `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.126`. This range is really close to `10.0.0.0/25` but lacking the /32 on both ends, guaranteeing that you will need 12 scopes to fill that range.

This problem can be represented like this:

```
               Start IP                         End IP
                  v                                v
-------|----------+----------------+---------------+-----------|------
       ^          .                                .           ^
  Subnet address  .                                .    Broadcast address
       .          .                                .           .
       .          \________________________________/           .
       .                     Provided Range                    .
       .                                                       .
       \_______________________________________________________/
                              Scope Range
```

You can solve those kind of problems most easily using a divide and conquer approach. In this case (and having in mind that a subnet mask is always a power of 2) we can split this problem (range `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.126` with /25 mask) in two smaller ones.

```
               Start IP                         End IP
                  v                                v
-------|----------+---------------++---------------+-----------|------
       ^                          ||                           ^
  Subnet address                  ||                    Broadcast address
       .                          ||                           .
       \__________________________/\___________________________/
       .          /X+1                        /X+1             .
       .                                                       .
       \_______________________________________________________/
                       Scope prefix length: /X
```

When you increase the prefix length you are basically splitting the scope in two. So instead of having a `10.0.0.0/25` you now have `10.0.0.0/26` and `10.0.0.64/26` and your two new ranges are `10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.63` and `10.0.0.64 - 10.0.0.126`. You would continue to split your ranges this way until:

1. Your  Start IP is equal to Subnet address **and** End IP is equal to Broadcast address
2. Your range is so small you can't split it further (/32).

This is the code I put together for this. All calculations are done on decimal representation of an IP address (not dotted-decimal), so the first two functions convert the `string` with IP in dotted-decimal notation to `long` and the other way around:

```
#include <sstream>
long str_to_long(string ip){
    stringstream s(ip);
    int o1, o2, o3, o4;
    char ch;
    s >> o1 >> ch >> o2 >> ch >> o3 >> ch >> o4;
    long ip_long = 0;
    ip_long = 0 | (o1 << 24) | (o2 << 16) | (o3 << 8) | o4;
    return ip_long;
}

string long_to_str(long ip){
    stringstream tmp;
    tmp << to_string((long long) ip >> 24 & 0xFF).c_str() << '.';
    tmp << to_string((long long) ip >> 16 & 0xFF).c_str() << '.';
    tmp << to_string((long long) ip >> 8 & 0xFF).c_str() << '.';
    tmp << to_string((long long) ip & 0xFF).c_str();
    return tmp.str();
}
```

The main function takes two (`long`) arguments — Start IP and End IP — and prints the required subnets.

```
void subnets(long start_ip, long end_ip){
    int host_bits = 0, host_mask = 0;
    long tmp = start_ip ^ end_ip;
    while(tmp != 0){
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
        host_bits++;
    }
    host_mask = (unsigned long)-1 >> (32 - host_bits);
    long network_addr = start_ip & (-1 ^ host_mask);
    long broadcast_addr = start_ip | host_mask;
    if(host_bits > 1){
        long split_low = (network_addr | host_mask >> 1);
        long split_high =(broadcast_addr & (-1 ^ host_mask >> 1));
        if(start_ip != network_addr || end_ip != broadcast_addr){
            subnets(start_ip, split_low);
            subnets(split_high, end_ip);
        }else{
            cout << long_to_str(start_ip) << "/" << 32-host_bits << endl;
        }
    }else{
        cout << long_to_str(start_ip) << "/" << 32-host_bits << endl;
    }
}
```

You can adopt this to put the subnets inside a vector (or whatever you want) instead of printing it to cout. So when we run this with the range i mentioned at the beginning `subnets(str_to_long("10.0.0.1"), str_to_long("10.0.0.126"))` you get the exact list of 12 subnets making that range.

```
10.0.0.1/32
10.0.0.2/31
10.0.0.4/30
10.0.0.8/29
10.0.0.16/28
10.0.0.32/27
10.0.0.64/27
10.0.0.96/28
10.0.0.112/29
10.0.0.120/30
10.0.0.124/31
10.0.0.126/32
```